# How to find given 2D point position based on axis system

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a axis system(origin,u direction,v direction).How to know given 2D point lie on the line which is used to denote the u or v direction line(ie, u=0 or v =0)?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If "given 2D point" P coordinates are presented in fixed coordinate system, then you have to represent vector **P-origin** in o-u-v basis.

```
op = P - origin

s * u.x + t * v.x = op.x
s * u.y + t * v.y = op.y
```

Solve last system of linear equations for unknown coefficients s and t. Check for zero coefficients.

Comment: Silent downvoting is the most silly thing. How could I know what is wrong here (if it is)?

Answer (score 0):

The axis OU has equation

```
Uy.(X - Ox) - Ux.(Y - Oy) = 0
```

and similarly for OV

```
Vy.(X - Ox) - Vx.(Y - Oy) = 0
```

Because of rounding errors, strict equality to zero will not hold, but if the vectors U and V are normalized,

```
|Uy.(X - Ox) - Ux.(Y - Oy)|
```

and

```
|Vy.(X - Ox) - Vx.(Y - Oy)|
```

are the shortest distances from the point `(X, Y)` to the axes.